# Migrating java stored procedures to AWS RDS oracle

Tags: java, oracle, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-rds

I am running into an issue with legacy java stored procedures on AWS RDS.  Since terminal/command line access is not provided on the RDS VMs, I cant install JVM.  Is the only way out by converting existing java stored procs into sql based ones?  If that is the case then it will be a pretty complicated one.  Any input will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

RDS Oracle does not support Java. You can confirm this, by running below command in sqlplus on RDS Oracle DB Instance.

```
select * from all_registry_banners;
```

If an Oracle database instance does support Java in the database, you will see a row similar to:

> Oracle Database Java Packages Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

Answer (score 1):

RDS now supports java. You enable it via an option group.
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/amazon-rds-for-oracle-now-supports-oracle-java/